# Hibernate : insert="false" update="false" column used in hibernate generated select query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a table called Loadout and it **doesn't** have a column called ProductName. But the hibernate xml has it because I need it to be fetch from another table for display purposes.

The Loadout.hbm.xml has a property called productName, which is `insert="false"` and `update="false".`

When `session.merge()` is being called, hibernate calls a select query and during that query the following error is issued.

> Hibernate: 
>       select
>           loadout0_.ID as ID225_0_,
>           loadout0_.NAME as NAME225_0_,
>           loadout0_.PRODUCT_ID as PRODUCT3_225_0_,
>           loadout0_.LOCATION_ID as LOCATION4_225_0_,
>           loadout0_.LOADOUT_LOADING_TIME_ID as LOADOUT5_225_0_,
>           loadout0_.TIME_SLOTS as TIME6_225_0_,
>           loadout0_.PRODUCT_NAME as PRODUCT7_225_0_ 
>       from
>           ETHANOL.LOADOUT loadout0_ 
>       where
>           loadout0_.ID=?
>
> 2015-07-14 19:28:31,410 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] >SQL Error: 904, SQLState:
>   42000 2015-07-14 19:28:31,410 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] ORA-00904:
>   "LOADOUT0_"."PRODUCT_NAME": invalid  identifier
>
> 2015-07-14 19:28:31,412 ERROR
>   [shipxpress.ethanol.server.location.web.LocationLoadoutSupport]
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQ LGrammarException: could not load an
>   entity: [shipxpress.ethanol.server.scheduling.domain.Loadout#27]

**This is the hbm config file.**

```
<id name="id" column="ID">
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">ETHANOL.LOADOUT_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
</id>
<property name="name" column="NAME" />
<property name="productId" column="PRODUCT_ID" />
<property name="locationId" column="LOCATION_ID" />
<property name="loadoutLoadingTimeId" column="LOADOUT_LOADING_TIME_ID" />


<property name="timeSlots" column="TIME_SLOTS" update="false" insert="false" />


<!--  The following property is causing the issue -->
<property name="productName"  column="PRODUCT_NAME"  update="false" insert="false" />
```

**SQL of the table**

```
CREATE TABLE "ETHANOL"."LOADOUT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "LOCATION_ID" NUMBER, 
    "LOADOUT_LOADING_TIME_ID" NUMBER
   );

ALTER TABLE "ETHANOL"."LOADOUT" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ID");
```

Comment: The names of the flags tell what they mean: `insert="false"`, `update="false"`. They don't mean `select="false"`. You could map another entity to the same table; just omit the mapping to the non-existing column in the new entity.